# In Inbox by Gmail, where is the new "Swipe to delete" setting?

Tags: ios, gmail

At the I/O conference yesterday, it was announced that Inbox would no longer require an invitation, and there were some feature improvements released. One of these was "swipe to delete," a feature I've been pining for for a while now. However, I can't figure out where the setting exists to enable this. I've checked https://support.google.com/inbox. I looked in both the Settings app and the settings option in the sidebar of Inbox itself, and no luck. Anyone managed to figure this out?

Comment: this is not the same as "swipe to delete." changing the action to take when done with message applies the action globally to all messages, after you've read them. "swipe to delete" allows you to delete messages individually without reading them, by swiping the message left or right in the messages list. (see mailbox app for what this feature actually looks like).

Comment: @garypetty you are correct, I am afraid. Overall I find Inbox an improvement over Mailbox.app, but I do miss that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inbox → Menu → Settings → *account* → Action to take when done with a message → Move to bin

Comment: Aha. The problem was, since I always have that app running, even though it had updated, the current process was the previous version. After hard-killing the app and restarting it, the option showed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > mail > select your email > account > advance setting > check deleted mailbox